# Display Issue with @vuepic/vue-datepicker: Seeking Solutions

Tags: javascript, datepicker, vuejs3

I am using the @vuepic/vue-datepicker library to manage 3 datepicker instances in my project, namely:

- Date + Time
- Date
- Time

However, the last one is not functioning as expected.

When I call my component with a default value, it is not displayed on the screen! Here is the source code for my component:

```js
<template>
  <Datepicker 
    v-model="time"
    :name="name"
    :defaultvalue="defaultvalue"
    time-picker
    cancelText="Cancel"
    selectText="Select"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { defineAsyncComponent, ref } from 'vue';
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css';

export default {
  components: {
    Datepicker: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('@vuepic/vue-datepicker')),
  },
  props: {
    defaultvalue: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  /**
   * Sets up the component based on the provided props.
   *
   * @param {object} props - The props object passed to the component.
   * @return {object} - An object containing the `time` property.
   */
  setup(props) {
    const timeString = props.defaultvalue;
    let time = ref();

    if (timeString !== '') {
      const [hours, minutes, seconds] = timeString.split(':').map(Number);
      time = ref({
        hours: hours,
        minutes: minutes,
        seconds: seconds
      });
    }

    return {
      time,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. We _all_ have issues and we're _all_ seeking solutions. Also, it's not evening here.

Comment: "_When I call my component with a default value_" what value is that?  Have you checked your browser's dev console for errors?  I ran your code in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/eloquent-varahamihira-jd829t?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A23%2C22) and it works fine.